# FX assessing if ListView is empty using different change listeners

Tags: listview, javafx, properties, changelistener

I want to assess whether a ListView is empty to disable or enable a submit button. So in essence, when the ListView has no content the button is disabled and when it has 1 or more elements it is enabled.

I've managed to achieve this using a ListChangeListener, using code such as:

```
vp.addListChangeListener(change -> {
        change.next(); 

        if (change.getList().size() == 0 && change.wasRemoved() || change.getList().size() == 1 && change.wasAdded()) {
            bp.toggleSubmitAvailability("submit");
        }
    });
```

where the method addListChangeListener is as follows:

```
public void addListChangeListener(ListChangeListener<Name> listener) {
    names.addListener(listener);
}
```

What I ideally wanted to do was just use a traditional ChangeListener and listen to one of the properties associated with the ListView. As an example, I thought this may work:

```
vp.addItemsListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        if (newValue.size() == 0 && oldValue.size() > 0 || newValue.size() == 1 && oldValue.size() == 0) {
            bp.toggleSubmitAvailability("submit");
        }
    });
```

where the method addItemsListener is as follows (and attaches a listener to the itemsProperty):

```
public void addItemsListener(ChangeListener<ObservableList<Name>> listener) {
        listView.itemsProperty().addListener(listener);
    }
```

However, for some reason, when I add items to my ListView, or well add items to the ObservableList that is attached to it, this property is not being changed, as nothing is happening - so what actually triggers the itemsProperty of the ListView to change, and if this approach will not work, is there a way to do what I did with the ListChangeListener by utilising another property associated with the ListView (in a reasonably elegant way of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `itemsProperty()` is the property that holds the list itself; listeners registered with it will get notified if you call `listView.setItems(...)`, (i.e. if the list reference itself is changed) but will not get notified if you modify the *content* of the list it contains (i.e. if you do `listView.getItems().add(...)`).

The `Bindings` class provides an [`isEmpty(ObservableList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) method you can use here:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems()));
```

or equivalently, with a listener:

```
Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems()).addListener(
    (obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> button.setDisable(isNowEmpty));
```

So you could implement a method like this:

```
public void addEmptyListListener(ChangeListener<Boolean> listener) {
    Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems()).addListener(listener);
}
```

and then do

```
vp.addEmptyListListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I have a similar problem like you are describing here, but I don't understand what represents 'vp' in the code, can you give me more details?